# Implementing t-SNE: problem when calculating pairwise affinities

Tags: self-study, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I'm trying to implement the t-SNE method. It's not a very complicated algorithm as it can be described like this:

[image]

I found that to compute the pairwise affinities, I have to follow this:

[image]

My problem is to compute $\sigma_i$ in this formula. In wikipedia I found:

> The bandwidth of the Gaussian kernels $\sigma_{i}$,
>   is set in such a way that the perplexity of the
>   conditional distribution equals a predefined perplexity using a binary
>   search. As a result, the bandwidth is adapted to the density of the
>   data: smaller values of $\sigma_{i}$ are
>   used in denser parts of the data space.

I don't understand what this realy mean. How can can I calculate $\sigma_i$ given data and perplexity?